# how to pass a value from servlet in javascript

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, servlets

I'm new to servlets and all this topic so sorry if it's a bit messy!
I'm trying to send a value from servlet to javascript or get value of a servlet method in java script.
I'm not sure about the `doGet`! am I doing it right ? getting the value of fields and sending the result to `javascript`?

**Servlet:**

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    try {
        String passengerCount = request.getParameter("passengerCount");
        String departureSchedule = request.getParameter("schedule");
        String arrivalSchedule = request.getParameter("returnschedule");
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        int departureSID = 0;
        int passengerCountInt = 0;
        userID = 0;
        int arrivalSID = 0;

        try {
            departureSID = Integer.parseInt(departureSchedule);
            passengerCountInt = Integer.parseInt(passengerCount);
            userID = Integer.parseInt(session.getAttribute("userID").toString());
            arrivalSID = Integer.parseInt(arrivalSchedule);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        if (departureSID != 0) {
            ScheduleBean departureSb = new ScheduleBean();
            departureSb.selectSchedule(departureSID);
            int departureRoute = departureSb.getRouteID();
            RouteBean routeB1 = new RouteBean();
            routeB1.selectRoute(departureRoute);
            double routeCharge = routeB1.getCharge();
            double totalDCharge = routeCharge * passengerCountInt;
            ReservationBean rb = new ReservationBean();
            UserBean us = new UserBean();

            if (arrivalSchedule == null) {
                rb.saveOneWayReservation(departureSID, userID, totalDCharge, passengerCountInt, "TICKET");
            } else {
                departureSb.selectSchedule(arrivalSID);
                int arrivalRoute = departureSb.getRouteID();
                routeB1.selectRoute(arrivalRoute);
                double arrivalRouteCharge = routeB1.getCharge();
                totalDCharge += arrivalRouteCharge * passengerCountInt;
                rb.saveRoundReservation(departureSID, arrivalSID, userID, totalDCharge, passengerCountInt, "TICKET");
            }

            ScheduleBean sbb = new ScheduleBean();
            sbb.selectSchedule(rb.scheduleID);
            AirBean bbb = new AirBean();
            bbb.selectAir(sbb.getAirID());
            String AirCode = bbb.getAirCode();
            String username = session.getAttribute("username").toString();
            int referenceNumber = rb.reservationID + 100;

            rb.updateTicketNumber(AirCode + "-" + username + "-" + String.valueOf(referenceNumber));
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Make payment</title>");
            out.println("<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js'></script>");
            out.println("<script type='text/javascript' src='js/payment.js'></script>");
            out.println("<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js'></script>");
            out.println("<link type='text/css' href='css/style.css' rel='Stylesheet' />");
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<div class='bg-light' style='width: 200px; height: 200px; position: absolute; left:50%; top:50%;  margin:-100px 0 0 -100px; padding-top: 40px; padding-left: 10px;'>");
            out.println("<input id='reservationID' style='display: none' value='" + rb.reservationID + "' />");
            out.println("<div>Credit Card Number : </div>");
            out.println("<div><input id='creditcard' onKeyPress='return checkIt(event);' type='text' name='creditcard' maxlength='16' /></div>");
            out.println("<div>ExpirationDate : </div>");
            out.println("<div><input id='expirationDate' type='text' onKeyPress='return checkIt(event);' name='expirationDate' maxlength='4' /></div>");
            out.println("<input type='hidden' id='FormName' name='FormName' value='" + HiddenValue + "'>");
            out.println("<div><input id='somebutton' type='button'  name='buttonsave' value='Make Payment' onclick='makePayment(" + rb.reservationID + ");' /></div>");
            out.println("<div><input type='button'  name='buttoncancel' value='Cancel Payment' onclick='cancelPayment(" + rb.reservationID + ");' /></div>");
            out.println("</div>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }
    } finally {
        out.close();
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get the value of the two input fields process on them and send the result to javascript

**Servlet doGet:**

```
    @Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);

    creditno = request.getParameter("creditcard");       //name of the input field, not id
    expiration = request.getParameter("expirationDate");     //name of the input field should be expirationDate
    UserBean us = new UserBean();
    boolean check = us.checkCC(userID, creditno, expiration); // process the fields 
    if (check == true) {
        CCA = "1";
    } else {
        CCA = "0";
    }

    response.setContentType("text/plain");  // Set content type of the response so that jQuery knows what it can expect.
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); // You want world domination, huh?
    response.getWriter().write(CCA);       // Write response body.

}
```

**Servlet doPost:**

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
var tempresp;
$(document).ready(function() {                        // When the HTML DOM is ready loading, then execute the following function...
    $('#somebutton').click(function() {               // Locate HTML DOM element with ID "somebutton" and assign the following function to its "click" event...
        $.get('MakeReservation', function(responseText) { // Execute Ajax GET request on URL of "someservlet" and execute the following function with Ajax response text...
            alert(responseText);
            tempresp=responseText;
        });
    });
});
```

Thanks In Advance!

Answer (score 0):

you have your java right, it is request.getParameter(...). However your not sending any data using javascript. If you want to send a "GET" request then use the code you have but make the following change:

```
$.get('MakeReservation?creditcard=12345&expirationDate=11%2F14', ....);
```

I would look up some JQuery tutorials on using the get and post methods. Also you may want to comment out that code you have and just test sending across some variables to get the hang of things before you dive right into that java side of things.

Comment: I checked my code and your suggested code in FireBug and both return an empty string! why is that ? it looks like that it's not getting the value from doGet!

Answer (score 0):

You're not sending any parameters to the Servlet. Even if you do, you'll encounter an `IllegalStateException`. It is because you're writing to the response body, using `out.println()`, and then setting headers. 
The statement

```
finally {
        out.close();
 }
```

also flushes the output stream, preventing you from writing any response headers.

Set any headers before writing to the response body and pass the required parameters in `$.get`

```
$.get('MakeReservation', {passengerCount: 2, arrivalSchedule: 123}, function(responseText) { // Execute Ajax GET request on URL of "someservlet" and execute the following function with Ajax response text...
          alert(responseText);
});
```

Comment: Hi! so what can I do inorder to make this work!
I've tried the second part of your suggestion and add parameter to the `$.get` but I'm receiving and empty string in javascript!

Comment: Try using `$.ajax({url: 'MakeReservation', data: {passengerCount: 2, arrivalSchedule: 123}, success: function(responseText) { alert(responseText); },error: function(xhr) { alert(xhr.status); })` in place of `$.get`. In the error handler, you must be getting a status code of `500`(Server error).

Comment: I used this `$.ajax({
url: 'MakeReservation', 
data: {passengerCount: 2, arrivalSchedule: 123}, 
success: function(responseText) { console.log(responseText); },
error: function(xhr) { alert(xhr.status); }});
    });`
and the result in the console is an empty string!